# Execute JavaScript before and after the f:ajax listener is invoked

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2.2

It there an easy way to invoke a JavaScript action before and after the invocation of an `<f:ajax listener>`, e.g. I'd like to invoke `window.alert("pre")` **before** and `window.alert("post")` **after** `onChange` is invoked in the backing bean `ACtrl`:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="anId" value="#{cityCtrl.dbHost}">
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{aCtrl.onChange}" execute="@all"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
public class ACtrlimplements Serializable {
    public void onChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("something changed");
    }
}
```

Adding multiple `f:ajax` elements doesn't seem to work (maybe it should?!), e.g. in

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="anId" value="#{cityCtrl.dbHost}">
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{aCtrl.toggle}" execute="@all"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{aCtrl.onChange}" execute="@all"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{aCtrl.toggle}" execute="@all"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
public class ACtrlimplements Serializable {
    public void onChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("something changed");
    }

    public void toggle(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("blah");
    }
}
```

only `ACtrl.onChange` is invoked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`onevent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) attribute. It must point to a callback function reference (so don't include parentheses!):

```html
<f:ajax ... onevent="functionName" />
```

Whereby the actual callback function look like this (JSF will provide the argument all by itself):

```
function functionName(data) {
    var status = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" or "success".
    var source = data.source; // The parent HTML DOM element.

    switch (status) {
        case "begin": // Before the ajax request is sent.
            // ...
            break;

        case "complete": // After the ajax response is arrived.
            // ...
            break;

        case "success": // After update of HTML DOM based on ajax response.
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) - tables 14.3 and 14.4
- [Is there a way to disable the command link until the ajax response is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734543/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-command-link-until-the-ajax-response-is-rendered/)
- [How to do double-click prevention in JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756426/how-to-do-double-click-prevention-in-jsf-2/)

Comment: How could I not have figured that out with the javadoc of onevent ('The name of the JavaScript function that will handle UI events.') myself... ;) Thanks!